# Update child objects in a nested form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My object is a Section. Each Section can have other Sections.
Section responds to #index, index returns its order index. 0 if a section does not have sibling sections.

Let's assume my data structure is:

```
   a
 /   \
b     c
```

Where:

a.index = 0

b.index = 0

c.index = 1

If I navigate to `/sections/a/manage-child-ordering`, I want to be able to edit the order of the subsections of `a`. This is the code in my view:

```
<% if @section.children %>
    <%= form_for @section do |child| %>
      <%= f.fields_for :children, @section.children do |c| %>
        <%= c.text_field :index %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn-submit' %>
```

The error I get:

```
undefined method `errors' for #<Tag::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f23e60bdbd0>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this in the model did the trick:

```
belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Section'
has_many :children, class_name: 'Section', foreign_key: :parent_id

accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
```

Comment: Do you mean the model?

Answer (score 0):

`form_for` should not take a collection, it should take just the single model which is responsible for implementing the action of the form. For you this is probably `@section` ie.

```
= form_for @section do |f|
```

Comment: updated and updated the new error message I am getting.

Comment: Then you'll have to show more code, like where you're setting that `@section` var (and what to).